# Как сделать список постов с сайта (картинка и текст) в ListView(java)?

Tags: java, android, listview, клиент

Я хочу сделать клиент для сайта. На сайте есть список постов, статей c картинкой и текстом. Как сделать список этих статей с картинкой и заголовком? Чтобы взять конкретную часть сайта использую парсер jsoup

Comment: Можно посмотреть [огромную кучу примеров](http://g.zeos.in/?q=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%20html%20jsoup) по данному вопросу.

Comment: а в чём проблема? в выводе полученных данных в `ListView`? Кстати, я бы использовал `RecyclerView`, если вы не намерены потом писать костыли, когда возникнут падения из-за _OutOfMemoryError_

Comment: @YaPV я знаю как парсить html, я спрашиваю как именно вставлять в Listview то что я напарсил (картинки и т.д.). Нужно чтобы был прокручиваемый список новостей например

Comment: Тогда я соглашусь с @ШураБалаганов. Читайте о RecyclerView.